# Google Maps only displays the last marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm loading information from the database (Firebase), but only the last marker is being created. I know the data is being loaded correctly and I have all the information I need to create the marker.

```
DataService.ds.REF_PARK.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
         if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
             for snap in snapshots {
                 if let parkDict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                     let park = Park(parkDict: parkDict)
                     self.createMarker(park)
                 }
             }
         }
     }) { (error) in
         print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
```

The function to create the marker is the following:

```
func createMarker(park: Park) {
     let marker = GMSMarker()
     marker.userData = park
     marker.title = park.parkName
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: park.parkCoordinates.lat, longitude: park.parkCoordinates.long)
     marker.map = mapView
}
```

This will only create the last marker. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you check with breakpoint.. how many times createMarker(:) called???

Comment: Also check you GMSCameraPosition and latitude and longitude of all Marker.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 it's called for every entry. I think the marker is being overwritten. I don't know why.

Comment: @Venkat what do you mean by that?

Comment: check that the Lat long of Marker is proper. if its proper then check whether is plotting outside the visible map region.